# Microsoft SysVAD Virtual Audio Device Driver (SYSVAD)

Tags: windows, audio, driver, wdk

This driver (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/audio/sysvad) works only under MS Windows 10. Did anybody try to move it to early Windows(7 or 8.1)? WDK 10 supports those OS.
Unfortunately my attempts were fail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It can be done but you need to exclude lots of features and code, since windows 7 or 8 may not supports new apis that are targeted for win 10.

If you are using Visual Studio simple workaround would be:

Go to property page > Driver setting  > Set Target OS version to Winows 7  and Target platform to Dektop. 
This will give you lots of error while compiling, now keep on removing code those can't be used targeted for win 7.